# Trying to create a simple RPG combat engine. Keep getting 'there is no argument given' errors

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create a simple combat game where you can pick your class, and you get different stats based on that class. I want to pass the integers to the combat method, but I'm running into trouble.

I keep getting `CS7036` errors saying "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter `Chance` of `MainGame.Combat(int, int, int)` For whatever reason, it's only Chance that's affected. I don't understand why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{

public class MainGame
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Character();
    }
    public static void Character()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Choose your class. Warrior or elf?");
        var charClass = Console.ReadLine();
        if (charClass.Equals("warrior", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            MainGame.Combat(20, 10, 15);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (charClass.Equals("elf", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            MainGame.Combat(20, 10, 15);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Combat Begins!");
        Combat();
    }

    public static void Combat(int Strength, int Chance, int Armor)
    {

        int HP = 100;

        while (HP > 0)
        {
            Random Dodge = new Random();
            int HitPercent = Dodge.Next(1, 101);

            if (HitPercent > MainGame.Combat(1) && HitPercent < 90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(HitPercent + "! Hit!");
                HP = (HP - (MainGame.Combat(0) - MainGame.Combat(2)));
                Console.WriteLine(HP + " HP remaining!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (HitPercent > 90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(HitPercent + "! Crit!");
                HP = (HP - MainGame.Combat(0));
                Console.WriteLine(HP + " HP remaining!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            else
                Console.WriteLine(HitPercent + "! Miss!");
                Console.WriteLine(HP + " HP remaining!");
                Console.ReadLine();

        }

        Console.WriteLine("You're dead!");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `MainGame.Combat(1)` ? `Combat();`? Combat takes 3 parameters, you're supplying 1 and 0, respectively.

Comment: The error message seems painfully clear to me. What is it you don't understand? What makes you think you can call a method that has 3 parameters, but provide fewer than that? (Note that it's _not "only `Chance`"_ that's affected...that just happens to be the first argument that's missing...the compiler doesn't waste time trying to tell you about the other argument that's missing.)

Comment: What I don't understand is what I'm doing wrong. I thought doing MainGame.Combat(x, x, x) would pass over all three stats. How is it only taking the one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one method called Combat. That method takes three parameters.  In several places, you're calling MainGame.Combat(0) or MainGame.Combat(1), which means you're only passing one parameter of the three required by the method.

Comment: Wow. I was going to ask how to only pass one parameter, then realized I could just use the integers themselves. Next step is figuring out how to add in an opponent character, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, also realize that you're currently calling the combat method recursively multiple times.  That's probably not what you want to do in this case.

Comment: Shouldn't I be using a loop until combat resolves and HP hits zero? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm not talking about the While loop, I'm talking about the recursion, where on each iteration of that loop, you have the function calling itself again (MainGame.Combat()).  It's obviously a mistake in this particular case anyway since you're comparing an integer to a void (the function returns void).

Comment: I swapped those out for the actual integers, though. Now the only instance of MainGame.Combat is in the character method, where I set the stats.